# Auth0 PKCE social authorization not supporting connection parameter

Tags: authentication, auth0, pkce

As per documentation Auth0's Authorization Code Grant Flow with PKCE does not support connection parameter as specified on this page.
https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/authorization-code-grant-pkce

I issued a `GET` request to `/authorize` end point for PKCE including all parameters as specified on the page above. Then I issues a post call to `/oauth/token` and I got token just fine.

However because of absence of connection parameter in `/authorize` end point (for PKCE) an intermediate auth0 page is opening (asking user to choose social connection to be used) and resulting an extra step for user. 
When I include connection parameter in `/authorize` call. It gave a code just like before. However this code cannot be used in `/oauth/token` call and I am getting

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Invalid authorization code"
}
```

every time in such case. Is this a defect or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: It looks like a defect so I am using this api anymore